# iPod Development Under Linux

Tags: linux, development-environment, ipod

I was thinking in start to develop iPod applications, the thing is that I use Linux(Ubuntu Hardy) and I don't know if I can develop on it, then I'm here asking for some resources and tutorials to begin. Thanks.

**Remember that I don't want to develop for iPod Touch, but for iPod Video**

Comment: Ten seconds worth of reading would have netted you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, development targeting Apple devices (iPod, iPod Touch, iPhone) can only be done through OS X because everything you need to develop your Interface (Interface Builder) and to test your app (Device Simulators) have only been release (by Apple) for OS X.

...don't tell anybody I told you this, but if you're only looking to distribute your app to Jailbroken devices (and not through the iTunes App Store), you can develop on Linux. Check out the link.

[Upgrading the iPhone Toolchain](http://www.saurik.com/id/4)